# Цвет текста в консоли

Tags: windows, c++

Подскажите, как настроить цвет текста в консоли? Ну, как бы что нужно писать? COLOR_WINDOWTEXT? И как?

**Добавлено.**

Ну, например, чтобы программа Hello world выводила зелёные буковки на экран.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Речь про программу для ОС Windows?

Comment: Да.

Comment: ну например что бы программа Hellow world выводила зелёные буковки на экран.

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}

Comment: http://otvety.google.ru/otvety/thread?tid=1d48fb68391867df

Comment: чё-то не очень помогло... По конкретней можно ?

Comment: Что именно не помогло? Попробуйте conio.h -> setcolor()

Comment: а вам зачем, если не секрет?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Visual C++ установка цвета последующего текста, например, в красный цвет делается так:

```
HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle, FOREGROUND_RED);
```

Для сборки подключить windows.h.

А в Borland C++ так:

```
textcolor(RED);
```

Для сборки подключить conio.h.

Comment: Помогло !

Comment: а как сделать что-бы цвет был таким только в cout<<"ТУТ";

Comment: Переопредели оператор <<

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/cout_color.aspx

Answer (score 4):

```
// устанавливает цвет текста и подложки  в консоли  
// 2 - значение цвета фона, 0 - значение цвета текста 
system("color 20" );
cout << "TEXT";
```

Атрибуты цветов задаются в виде ДВУХ шестнадцатеричных цифр -- первая
задает цвет фона, а вторая определяет цвет переднего плана. Каждая цифра может
иметь следующие значения:

- 0 = Черный 8 = Серый
- 1 = Синий 9 = Светло-синий
- 2 = Зеленый A = Светло-зеленый
- 3 = Голубой B = Светло-голубой
- 4 = Красный C = Светло-красный
- 5 = Лиловый D = Светло-лиловый
- 6 = Желтый E = Светло-желтый
- 7 = Белый F = Ярко-белый