# Как поменять цвет отдельного символа в консольном приложении?

Tags: c, windows, консоль

Как поменять цвет отдельного символа в консольном приложении. Язык C. Компилятор - VS.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Цвет текста в консоли](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16431/%d0%a6%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Для консоли вызвать функцию SetConsoleTextAttribute, передав в аргументе wAttributes требуемый цвет символа.
- Для окна вызвать функцию SetTextColor, также передав в аргументе нужный цвет текста.

После того, как символ выведен, вернуть прежний цвет.

Comment: Можете привести рабочий код ?